# What does "canonical answer" refer to in bountied question notices?

Tags: support, bounty

I sometimes go through the bountied questions in Ask Ubuntu.

Often I see the notice indicating the reason for offering the bounty is a specific reason written manually.

Other standard noticed like "Want to reward existing answer" are easily understood.

But [Gnome 3 standard brightness control with external monitor](https://askubuntu.com/q/1285463/739431) this question has a notice saying the person offering the bounty

> is looking for a canonical answer

So, I am confused - does Canonical have a system linked to Ask Ubuntu bountied questions? I mean when the person chooses this option "looking for a canonical answer," will Canonical be notified?

The OP wants an answer from Canonical, and it seems they are very clear in the question that they don't want help in writing scripts or keybindings etc.

Is that really possible? Canonical will answer this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a bit of confusion on your part, you seem to be confusing the company Canonical who make Ubuntu with the English meaning of the word, it is an easy mistake to make here, a relevant definition of the word (from [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/canonical?s=t) via Zanna in comments)

> authorized; recognized; accepted:

So what they actually want is a definitive or best answer to the question rather than an answer from the developers.

This is a common term through out Stack Exchange, my explanation is not great so here are some examples from various sites

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose

[Meaning of "Canonical answer required" bounty category](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185778/meaning-of-canonical-answer-required-bounty-category)

https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7115/what-is-a-canonical-answer

https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/what-is-a-canonical-question-exactly

Comment: So in simple.. Canonical in the "Canonical Answer required" is not the canonical company??

Comment: Yes, "Canonical Answer required" is a default bounty reason on all sites and has no connection to the Ubuntu devs, the name is just an, admittedly confusing, coincidence.